# How to Display All the Values Calculated In A Variable in BOXI 3.7

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, crosstab

I'm working in BOXI 3.1 SP7.  I'm new to it.

I have a variable whose value is based on the values in another column.

I'm trying to use the variable in another crosstab.  When I use it, it is not showing the entire set of values.

[image]

It has 4 possible values but its showing only 1 value.  The other values are shown as `#MULTIVALUE`.

I have created the variable as a *dimension*.

Please help me to display all the values properly.

Here is the variable definition.

```
   =If ([# Price Chngs] > 0) Then
( "Brazil" )
ElseIf ([# Account Changes] > 0 And [# Instruction Changes] > 0)
Then
( "Argentina" )
ElseIf ([# Trading Account Chngs] > 0)
Then
( "Argentina" )
ElseIf ([# Account Changes]>0 And [# Code Changes]>0 And [# Instruction Changes] > 0 )
Then
("Argentina")
ElseIf ([# Account Changes]>0 And [# Code Changes]>0 And [# Instruction Changes] > 0 And [# Date Changes] > 0)
Then
( "Argentina" )
ElseIf ([# Date Changes] > 0)
Then
( " Chile " )
ElseIf ([# Code Changes]>0)
Then
( "Argentina" )
ElseIf ([# Code Changes]>0 And [# Quantity Chngs] > 0)
Then
( " Brazil " )
Else 
 ( "Others" )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the definition of the variable?

Comment: @Joe, Hi Joe, please find the variable definition above.

Answer (score 2):

The `#MULTIVALUE` error means you're trying to show multiple values in one place and WebI doesn't know how to aggregate them. It' a common error for measure objects and to a lesser extent for detail objects, but not for a dimension.

The only way to get a **dimension object** to trigger the `#MULTIVALUE` error is to create a cell instead of a table and then put the dimension object in there. As dimensions cannot be aggregated, Webi doesn't know how to display it and reverts to `#MULTIVALUE`.

Some remarks:

- Looking at the screenshot, it seems that you've tried to build your own cross tab instead of just using the cross tab object and then add the dimension and measure objects. Check the tutorials [Create a table](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21120) and [Change the layout of a table](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21116) to see how to create the different types of tables.
- Are you sure you created the variable as a dimension object and not as a measure? If you used an aggregate function in your variable definition, Webi might have changed the object type to measure.

Answer (score 0):

What this error means is that the row with the error has multiple values, either what's being evaluated in the variable, or what it's displaying.  There are three basic solutions:

- Add all of the input variables ([# Price Chngs], [# Account Changes], [# Instruction Changes], [# Trading Account Chngs], [# Code Changes], [# Date Changes], [# Quantity Chngs]) as report elements
- Wrap the variable in a Sum()
- Wrap each of the variables in the variable in a Sum()

Without seeing your data, I can't recommend a specific solution, but one of the solutions above should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Check your table definition by viewing the structure.  What I notice is that the one value displayed in your cross tab, "Price/Quantity", is not one of the possible values in your variable definition. I suspect the variable isn't included in the table where you think it is.